# User comments do not show up on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

some days ago I've published an app on Google Play. When I log into the Google Play Developer Console I can see user comments about my app. When I visit my app's site on Google Play, however, these comments are not visible.

Does anybody know how I can get these comments to become visible on my app's site on Google Play?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Comment in Google Play store separate for different countries. May be this is the reason why you don't see it. Try to use proxy. There is no way for you to change this behavior.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. If I switch to English on the Google Play site, the comments suddenly appear.

Comment: I can see comments on computer but they dont appear on mobile. How to fix it?

Answer (score 26):

At this moment you don't need to use proxy.

You can simply add to URL `&hl=en` where `en` is two-letter language code defined in [ISO 639-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)

For example:

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=en
  (English)
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=pl
  (Polish)
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=it
  (Italian)
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=fr
  (French)
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=es
  (Spanish)

Comment: This is the right answer and needs to be accepted to be the right answer.

Comment: That works well without having to change your preferences. It's still pretty annoying not to be able to just see all comments if we want, even from a consumer's point of view.

Comment: I can see comments on computer but they dont appear on mobile. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Google play shows reviews if your language is suitable to apps language.To show reviews add &hl= apps_language like (ru or en) to the end of url.